# How can put variable in tn.write?

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnetlib

I want to put a variable in script that i made

let's say

`host = 192.168.1.1`

and my comment in the script is :

```
tn.write("cpconf tohost=192.168.200.22:XXX \n")
```

my request :
want that instead `XXX` the variable it is will be host

how can  do it ?
use `Python2.7`.

Comment: `tn.write("cpconf tohost=192.168.200.22:{0} \n".format(host))`

Comment: As a beginner, you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still write it do it because we have to support legacy code. Please consider installing Python 3.9 and learning to write in that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tn.write("cpconf tohost=192.168.200.22:{0} \n".format(host))
```

Working! thanks